How can my blue and black deck return enchantments from the graveyard?
I’ve created a blue and black deck, the concept is to create damage with enchantments, like Dark Tutelage or Stab Wound and to neutralize creatures or spells with essence scatter and other neutralize cards. My problem is I haven’t found a way to get the instants and enchantments back in my hand from the graveyard and I’ve tried to research and only found white cards that could do that. If anyone has a great idea, to get the spells back.

Welcome to the Color Pie, some things are deliberately not possible in some colours. At the very least, please specify which format you are playing - you've tagged this both mtg-arena and mtg-multiplayer which at least at the moment are inconsistent as there is no multiplayer on Arena.

I play normal cards, so I would say multiplayer?

What is “dark tulag”? That seems to be a typo, there's no card by that name.

"Multiplayer" in an MTG context means more than 2 players, almost exclusively Commander. Sounds like you're playing "kitchen table magic" (not a pejorative term) meaning "no special rules"?

@doppelgreener I'm going to guess wildly at Dark Tutelage but that doesn't do what the poster wants unless they somehow donate it to their opponent.

Wait, yes I mean dark tutelage. But how is it donating or did I miss understand the card

In the vast majority of circumstances, Dark Tutelage applies to you only ("at the beginning of your upkeep") and causes damage to you only. Donate is MtG slang for something that causes an opponent to gain control of one of your permanents.

There is no such format as "multiplayer", and "normal" doesn't identify a subset of cards in any meaningful way. Presumably, you play casually, "at the kitchen table" in the vernacular, and not in a sanctioned format (competitive or otherwise). That's fine; a large majority of MTG players do exactly that. But rules discussion tends to revolve around competitive play, where it matters more. (and Commander, which is typically casual but is full of people who like to flex their rules knowledge.)

Anyway, the bigger question is why you are particularly concerned with getting enchantments back from the graveyard. Is it because you are playing "self-mill" effects that put cards directly into the graveyard? Is it because you play enchantments that can be sacrificed for a benefit? If not - if you're just worried about getting them back after you "lost" them - then you are probably doing the strategy wrong. There are plenty more enchantments in your deck anyway, and effects that can destroy enchantments on the battlefield are relatively rare. Counterspells? You play blue, play some yourself.

Also, to support your deck you might want to consider cards that duplicate enchantments (like "Estrid's Invocation" and "mirror made") as well as cards that return themselves (Screams from Within)

What format are you playing, because it will definitely matter. If it's not commander you may have some options like Lurrus of the Dream-Den (if it's one of the few formats she's not banned in) where the hybrid mana symbols let you bypass the color pie issues others have mentioned.
Kaervek, the Punisher Is a new card from Outlaws of Thunder Junction that will in some ways do what you were wanting, because he lets you cast a copy of black cards in the graveyard, you would get a token copy, but this is a one time deal, like flashback the actual card gets exiled, so you can't use it again. Reenact the Crime works in much the same way, letting you play a copy of card the turn it went to graveyard, and could be used to catch enchantments as they are removed once.
For legendary enchantments or sagas, you could make some use of Rona, Disciple of Gix as a one off, since she would exile a historic card from your graveyard and then let you cast that card from exile.
Xiahou Dun, the One-Eyed can return any black card from your graveyard to your hand but you need to sacrifice him to do it, which would be another one shot option.
Forbidden Crypt is a possible option, but is dangerous to play too early, since it returns cards from your grave as a replacement for drawing, with the same empty loss condition.
The other, and mostly better, options have been covered by other answers - there is no good way to do this with black and blue, because that's just not what black and blue do.

Unfortunately for you, this is just not something blue and black really do. You haven't specified what format you're playing, but it's true for almost all formats.
From the color pie 2021 article, we can see the different ways returning things is divided among the colors. Most notably if you expand the “M–R” section and find “Return target creature from graveyard to hand”, we see a breakdown of the different types that can be returned and which colors do them.

Black returns creatures.
Blue returns instants and sorceries
The color that returns enchantments is white.

Additionally, green can often return cards of any type (e.g. Eternal Witness).
Blue and black are the strongest colors at card draw, so in those colors your resources are better spent focusing on drawing new enchantments rather than trying to get old ones back. Alternately, you should add white to the deck and use white's enchantment synergies: white-blue-black decks do quite well in most environments.

Okey, than I’m going to research a bit more.

While enchantment return is definitely outside of the color pie for black and blue, there are a small number of options - including some colorless ones. However, breaking the color pie usually comes at a cost of efficiency.
Here are some ones I could find:

Crystal Chimes
Gerrard's Hourglass Pendant
Saprazzan Bailif
Skull of Orm

For instants, blue has a lot of tools that will either return them to your hand, or your library, or just let you cast them from the graveyard. Scryfall has about 85 such cards that might be worth a look.

Thank you. That is perfect!

Just to add a bit of information, there are also some cards that can return any type of card, but they're not really efficient. Some examples include Codex Shredder and Conqueror's Galleon.

Thanks for noting that. You can dig through Scryfall with searches like o-tag:regrowth or o-tag:recursion to find some of the more generic ones for sure.

Instants are pretty easy, there are a bunch of blue cards that do that (here’s a simple Scryfall search listing all of the cards in blue and black that return instants to your hand). Said // Done would probably be my first pick for this, there’s not much that’s less expensive to cast, and it gives you a useful tool to stall creature-focused decks with if you need it.
Enchantments are much harder, as enchantment reanimation/retrieval effects are pretty much exclusively white. The only real options that do that specifically in blue/black are Crystal Chimes, Odunos River Trawler, and Gerrard’s Hourglass Pendant. None of them is a great option, the chimes are slow or expensive, the trawler only gives you about 2/3 of it’s value unless you add some way to generate a bit of white mana (but if you’re going to do that, why not enough to just splash proper white cards for this?), and the pendant is only really good for one or two items despite it’s cost. Aside from those, your best options are probably Yawgmoth's Will (if it’s legal in the format you’re playing), and Magus of the Will, both of which let yo cast things directly from your graveyard.
Alternatively, if you have lots of card draw (and you should in a serious blue/black deck), cards that put things back into your library (sometimes called ‘restock’ effects), like Memory’s Journey, Devious Cover-Up or Oracle of Tragedy, may be acceptable without needing to diversify colors (blue has a lot of these), but most are pretty restrictive in what you can put back or where exactly it goes.

As an aside, if you just have a specific aversion to adding white,  adding some green instead also gives you Season of Renewal, and you could consider Muldrotha, the Gravetide, Gaea’s Will, and possibly Revival Experiment, Squirming Emergence, and Kagha, Shadow Archdruid.
